How to add brackets to the number of a journal volume?
In the following MWE, the number of a journal volume — {3} — has to be written between brackets — (3) — with italics as follow: 92 (3), with no space between 92 and (3). How to do it?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]   {title}{#1\isdot}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{Chiantaretto2005,
author = {Chiantaretto, Jean-François}, 
title = {À propos de la première transgression}, 
journal = {Topique}, 
volume = {92}, 
number = {3}, 
pages = {111--125}, 
year = {2005}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \autocite{Chiantaretto2005}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


You could change the format of the number field like this:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]   {title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibemph{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{Chiantaretto2005,
author = {Chiantaretto, Jean-François}, 
title = {À propos de la première transgression}, 
journal = {Topique}, 
volume = {92}, 
number = {3}, 
pages = {111--125}, 
year = {2005}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \autocite{Chiantaretto2005}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


